# access media from umbraco forms.cshtl

Tags: forms, umbraco, media

I'm trying to show images from the mediapicker in a umbraco form.

I can get the ID of the image without a problem but the namespace Media doesn't exist.
@Include doesn't work becouse forms uses @model and there can only be one @model in a partial view...

So I have the ID and with that I want to get the name and Url of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the media object via the UmbracoHelper like this (1234 being your media id):

```
@{
   var media = Umbraco.TypedMedia(1234);
   var image = media.Url;
   var name = media.Name;
}
```

This gets an IPublishedContent.

Here is the documentation for the UmbracoHelper
https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Querying/UmbracoHelper/

If you don't have a UmbracoHelper you can initialize a new one like this:

```
var umbracoHelper = new Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper(Umbraco.Web.UmbracoContext.Current);

var media = umbracoHelper.TypedMedia(1234);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I missed the part about the helper. That solved the problem instantly.